# "Debug Adapter Executable not provide" in VS code for Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Try to debug the Python code in Container using VS Code Remote Container Extension.

After the docker build task,  I got a "Debug Adapter Executable not provide" error. Where could be wrong?

[image]

launch.json

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Docker: Python - General",
        "type": "docker",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "docker-run: debug",
        "python": {
            "pathMappings": [
                {
                    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                    "remoteRoot": "/app"
                }
            ],
            "projectType": "general"
        }
    }
]
```

}

tasks.json

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "docker-build",
        "label": "docker-build",
        "platform": "python",
        "dockerBuild": {
            "tag": "py:latest",
            "dockerfile": "${workspaceFolder}/Dockerfile",
            "context": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "pull": true
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "docker-run",
        "label": "docker-run: debug",
        "dependsOn": [
            "docker-build"
        ],
        "python": {
            "file": "app.py"
        }
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Can [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/docker-compose#_debug) help?

Comment: The comment above the error in VS Code on Github is "// Unlikely scenario" lol
See here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/blob/main/src/client/debugger/extension/adapter/factory.ts#:~:text=//%20Unlikely%20scenario.,provided%27)%3B

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it is resolved if you define a local python interpreter even if you want to use docker. Open a .py file and define it with the button right bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem. After trying a fresh install of the VS Code Docker extension, to no avail, I noticed the actually command being triggered by the `"docker-run: debug"` task in the `tasks.json`:

```
docker run -dt -P --name "loadtiktokcampaigns-dev" --label 
"com.microsoft.created-by=visual-studio-code" -v 
"/Users/tnightengale/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-
2022.12.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy:/debugpy:ro,z" 
--entrypoint "python3" "loadtiktokcampaigns:latest"
```

The key here is the `-v` command that is attempting to mount the `/debugpy` files into the container from the VS Code Python extension files.

For some reason, those files were not actually located at that path on my Mac. Deleting the `ms-python.python-2022.12.0/` folder and reinstalling the [VS Code Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) solved the issue for me.